# How do I read from JSON File in Java?

Tags: java, json, file

I've read some other questions about this, but they did not seem to help me.
As the title says, I want to know how to read from .json files using Java.
Eg. I want my program to read a boolean value. (That is what I want it to.)

I really hope you will be able to help me with this. I am able to use json-simple-1.1.1 if needed.

What I've found so far (That did not work):

```
    String str = "Name";
    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
    String n = (String) obj.get("Name");
    if (!n.equals("true")) {

    } else
    if (n.equals("true")) {
        ButtonsShow = true;
    } else if (n.equals("false")) {
        ButtonsShow = false;
    }
```

[Click to view the .Json file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b4B8u.png)

Answer (score 0):

you try it:

```
  import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Iterator;
import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;
import org.json.simple.parser.ParseException;

public class JsonSimpleExample {
     public static void main(String[] args) {

    JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();

    try {

        Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader("c:\\test.json"));

        JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;

        String name = (String) jsonObject.get("name");
        System.out.println(name);

        long age = (Long) jsonObject.get("age");
        System.out.println(age);

        // loop array
        JSONArray msg = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("messages");
        Iterator<String> iterator = msg.iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println(iterator.next());
        }

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

     }

}
```

Comment: take a look at it : http://www.mkyong.com/java/json-simple-example-read-and-write-json/

Comment: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/json/json_java_example.htm

Comment: Read that link, I don't see it says anything about how to read JSON using Java? Can you please show me?

Comment: what do you mean? you read those things. do it yourself. it uses java

Comment: Sorry. Alright so I am trying to read the JSON. Right now I use this code (Below). But when I try to toggle the buttons, it keeps doing as if it the boolean was set to true. By the way. I know the options.json is set to false.

Comment: JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
      Object obj = null;
  try {
   obj = parser.parse(new FileReader("Options.json"));
  } catch (ParseException e) {
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
       JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;
       Boolean truth = (Boolean) jsonObject.get("Button");
     
       if (truth.valueOf(true)) {
        ButtonsShow = true;
        System.out.print(obj);    
       } else if (truth.valueOf(false)) {
       ButtonsShow = false;
        System.out.print(obj);    
        
       }

Comment: By the way, I use a loop that runs every 1ms.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/men3wt58wgkuvd6/Options.json?dl=1

Comment: {"button":false}   i have got on it.

Comment: you can get it like String button = (String) jsonObject.get("button");

Comment: I get this error. Any idea why? java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Boolean cannot be cast to java.lang.String - I can't see why myself..

Comment: Nevermind - Fixed it. Thanks!